# XSLT group-by specific date range

Tags: xslt, mapping

I've the following xml & want to regroup the elements as per specific date ranges.

**Input xml:**

`

```
<cust_CD>
   <user>
      <userId>50298867</userId>
      <cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
         <cust_EndDate>2023-05-31T00:00:00.000</cust_EndDate>
         <cust_startdate>2023-01-01T00:00:00.000</cust_startdate>
         <cust_percentage>20</cust_percentage>
         <cust_costCenter>N3020050</cust_costCenter>
         <cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>50298867</cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>
      </cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
      <cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
         <cust_EndDate>2023-02-28T00:00:00.000</cust_EndDate>
         <cust_startdate>2023-01-01T00:00:00.000</cust_startdate>
         <cust_percentage>40</cust_percentage>
         <cust_costCenter>NT7000003</cust_costCenter>
         <cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>50298867</cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>
      </cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
      <cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
         <cust_EndDate>2023-01-31T00:00:00.000</cust_EndDate>
         <cust_startdate>2023-01-01T00:00:00.000</cust_startdate>
         <cust_percentage>40</cust_percentage>
         <cust_costCenter>N2030020</cust_costCenter>
         <cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>50298867</cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>
      </cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
   </user>
</cust_CD>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<group>
   <date>
      <effectiveDate>2023-01-01T00:00:00.000</effectiveDate>
      <cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
         <cust_EndDate>2023-05-31T00:00:00.000</cust_EndDate>
         <cust_startdate>2023-01-01T00:00:00.000</cust_startdate>
         <cust_percentage>20</cust_percentage>
         <cust_costCenter>N3020050</cust_costCenter>
         <cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>50298867</cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>
      </cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
      <cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
         <cust_EndDate>2023-02-28T00:00:00.000</cust_EndDate>
         <cust_startdate>2023-01-01T00:00:00.000</cust_startdate>
         <cust_percentage>40</cust_percentage>
         <cust_costCenter>NT7000003</cust_costCenter>
         <cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>50298867</cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>
      </cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
      <cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
         <cust_EndDate>2023-01-31T00:00:00.000</cust_EndDate>
         <cust_startdate>2023-01-01T00:00:00.000</cust_startdate>
         <cust_percentage>40</cust_percentage>
         <cust_costCenter>N2030020</cust_costCenter>
         <cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>50298867</cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>
      </cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
   </date>
      <date>
      <effectiveDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</effectiveDate>
      <cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
         <cust_EndDate>2023-05-31T00:00:00.000</cust_EndDate>
         <cust_startdate>2023-01-01T00:00:00.000</cust_startdate>
         <cust_percentage>20</cust_percentage>
         <cust_costCenter>N3020050</cust_costCenter>
         <cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>50298867</cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>
      </cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
      <cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
         <cust_EndDate>2023-02-28T00:00:00.000</cust_EndDate>
         <cust_startdate>2023-01-01T00:00:00.000</cust_startdate>
         <cust_percentage>40</cust_percentage>
         <cust_costCenter>NT7000003</cust_costCenter>
         <cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>50298867</cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>
      </cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
   </date>
   <date>
      <effectiveDate>2023-03-01T00:00:00.000</effectiveDate>
      <cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
         <cust_EndDate>2023-05-31T00:00:00.000</cust_EndDate>
         <cust_startdate>2023-01-01T00:00:00.000</cust_startdate>
         <cust_percentage>20</cust_percentage>
         <cust_costCenter>N3020050</cust_costCenter>
         <cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>50298867</cust_MDFCostDistribution_Parent_usersSysId>
      </cust_MDFCostDistribution_child>
   </date>
   <date>
      <effectiveDate>2023-06-01T00:00:00.000</effectiveDate>
   </date>
</group>
```

**The logic behind is:** Each child element has a start/end date range (cust_startdate/cust_EndDate). Only the elements falls between the date-range will be grouped together. When, for any specific element(s) end-date is over, the rest elements excluding them, need to be re-grouped from next day onwards. So that, effective dates can be maintained.

'**'

In output xml, the 'effectiveDate' comes from cust_EndDate + 1Day ' + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')'. This is because, we need to determine which elements are effective on particular dates. For Ex: all 3 are valid from 2023-01-01(1st effective date/Initial one) till 2023-01-31. 2 valid between 2023-02-01(2nd effective date) to 2023-02-28. Only 1 valid between 2023-03-01(3rd effective date) to 2023-05-31. And none after 2023-06-01 onwards. Hope I clarifies.

'**'

Will welcome any help/suggestion regarding the matter.

Thank You

Not really able to find an way. Tried with group-starting-with & group-ending-with functions, but that didn't resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow the required logic correctly (which is not at all certain), you want to do something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/cust_CD">
    <group>
        <xsl:call-template name="find-overlaps">
            <xsl:with-param name="x-date" select="min(user/cust_MDFCostDistribution_child/xs:dateTime(cust_startdate))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="find-overlaps">
    <xsl:param name="x-date"/>
    <xsl:variable name="overlaps" select="user/cust_MDFCostDistribution_child[xs:dateTime(cust_startdate) le $x-date and $x-date le xs:dateTime(cust_EndDate)]" />
    <date>
        <effectiveDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="$x-date"/>
        </effectiveDate>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$overlaps"/>
    </date> 
     <xsl:if test="$overlaps">
        <xsl:call-template name="find-overlaps">
            <xsl:with-param name="x-date" select="min($overlaps/xs:dateTime(cust_EndDate)) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes that every `cust_MDFCostDistribution_child` node overlaps another to some extent, or is at least adjacent to another. If there can be two or more completely separate, discontiguous ranges, then this needs more work.